# Find the sum of the series of $c^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series

No clue on how to attack this without brute forcing. My main problem is how do i get rid of the sqrt while also finding the sum of $c^i$?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sqrt {4^i} $$

Comment: $\sqrt{4^i} = 4^{i/2} = (4^{1/2})^i = 2^i$ or you can find it directly since it's only from 1 to 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are only three terms, it doesn't seem like much of a problem to write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sqrt {4^i} = \sqrt{4^1}+\sqrt{4^2}+\sqrt{4^3} = \sqrt 1+ \sqrt{16} + \sqrt{64} = 1+4+8 = 13.
$$
However, if you want to get rid of the radical before summing, you can write $\sqrt{4^i} = 2^i$ so that then you have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 2^i.
$$

Comment: $\sqrt{64}\ne16$